# How to maintain encapsulation whilst wrapping multiple API classes which interact?

Tags: oop, encapsulation, word-wrap

I have API classes A and B, which I've wrapped, say WrappedA and WrappedB. Now I need to call A.AddMappingTo(B) in such a way where i can call WrappedA.AddMappingTo(WrappedB), whats the best method of doing this?

**Option 1: Internal members. WrappedA can see WrappedB.B.**

```
// class WrappedA
public void AddMappingTo(WrappedB wrappedB)
{
    a.AddMappingTo(wrappedB.b);
}
```

Feels like it breaks encapsulation?

**Option 2: Internal functions. WrappedA can see WrappedB.AddMappingFrom(A) which calls A.AddMappingTo(B).**

```
// class WrappedA
public void AddMappingTo(WrappedB wrappedB)
{
    wrappedB.AddMappingFrom(a);
}

//class WrappedB
public void AddMappingFrom(A a)
{
    a.AddMappingTo(b);
}
```

Feels like it breaks cohesion - now both WrappedA and WrappedB have functions which involve mapping to each other?

Any other options?

Comment: Maybe you can try to explain more on a higher level what you want to archieve? Maybe there is an alternative way?

Comment: I have code which must use an awful API so I'm writing an adapter layer / framework layer to wrap the API calls into something sensible so both myself and other developers can use the framework as a much nicer interface to the API.